# React (Jumpsuit) - errors not showing in console unless I try/catch

Tags: reactjs, debugging, redux, try-catch, silent

I'm building a webapp with [Jumpsuit](https://github.com/jumpsuit/jumpsuit) and I'm noticing a weird error. Things that usually cause an error to be printed to the console in React are not doing so, unless I specifically put that code in a try catch block.

For example, in the render method of one component I have this:

```
render () {
    return (
        <div>
            ...
            <div>{this.loadQuestionDropdowns()}</div>
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

and in `loadQuestionDropdowns()` I have this return to test it:

```
{
    ...
    return <Potato />
}
```

Now, Potato is not an actual component, nor anything I've imported. Usually if you try this the console will show a reference error saying 'Potato' is not defined. However, it just crashes the app and nothing shows up in the console. If I wrap it in a try catch block:

```
    try {return (<Potato />);}
    catch (e) {console.log(e);}
```

Then it prints the error:

```
ReferenceError: Potato is not defined
    at Object.loadQuestionDropdowns (transformData.js:19)
    at Object.render (transformData.js:19)
    at p._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (InterceptorManager.js:52)
    at p._renderValidatedComponent (InterceptorManager.js:52)
    at p._updateRenderedComponent (InterceptorManager.js:52)
    at p._performComponentUpdate (InterceptorManager.js:52)
    at p.updateComponent (InterceptorManager.js:52)
    at p.receiveComponent (InterceptorManager.js:52)
    at Object.receiveComponent (createError.js:16)
```

and the app continues to run. I've noticed this behaviour in a few other scenarios too. I've built things with React, Redux and Jumpsuit before and haven't encountered this. I looked it up and it seems Promises are something that can silently swallow errors but I don't use any Promises in my own code and when I do state updates via Jumpsuit I always catch/throw errors. My NODE_ENV=development and for building I just use Jumpsuit's built in build script `jumpsuit build`. I read one post that said it was an issue with their webpack configuration but I don't use webpack, my package.json settings are:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "build": "jumpsuit build && babel server --out-dir dist/server"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015",
      "react",
      "stage-2"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "transform-object-rest-spread"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.22.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0"
  }
}
```

Any ideas on why this could behaviour is occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this was already raised on the internal issue tracker:
https://github.com/jumpsuit/jumpsuit/issues/3

Although it doesn't seem to address it directly in their response. This is also noticeable in other redux/react libraries namely `redux-saga`.
For example: https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/632 - although it isn't exactly the same thing, it is related.

I would suggest getting together a most-minimal example on webpackbin (the demo site they use at the project) and submit an issue (or better yet, a PR to fix it).

Comment: Yeah looks like I might be having to go to creators directly. Thanks